# Java Calendar.getInstance() changing the default timezone in Linux

Tags: java, datetime, calendar, simpledateformat

Please see my code as below :

```
SimpleDateFormat sd = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
calendar.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);  
sd.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));
System.out.println(sd.format(calendar.getTime()));
```

My Windows system's default time zone is EDT at this moment and time when I ran this code is (28/09/2016 12:27 PM)and when I run this code in the system the output I get as below -- which is intended (EDT to GMT Conversion) :

```
28/09/2016 04:00:00
```

But when I run this on server (Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 5.11) the output I get as below :

```
28/09/2016 00:00:00
```

When I ran the below command to the Linux shell

```
date +%Z
```

It returned below output

```
EDT
```

So, I am not able to understand why the conversion did not happen. Also, I have a piece of code like below :

```
SimpleDateFormat sd = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
sd.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));
System.out.println(sd.format(calendar.getTime()));
```

Which returned below output (ran it on 28/09/2016 12:36 PM) in the same Linux Server with the intended output that is converted it to GMT

```
28/09/2016 16:36:46
```

This code is part of a J2EE application running on WebLogic 12c. Please share if you have any clue, what might have caused the above mentioned scenario. Thanks.

Comment: If I recall correctly, there is a setting in startWeblogic (or similar, it's been several years since I used weblogic) to override the system timezone and use GMT (by default). You can validate this by logging `Calendar.getInstance().getTimeZone().toString()` somewhere.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch I checked that, and it returned GMT, but I am not sure then how the second piece of code working, it should not convert then.

Comment: Can't reproduce the issue with code provided. Are you showing us the real code, or code that is similar to the real code?

Comment: Which part you are not able to reproduce? Also, when I am running it on my Windows both cases it is working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're relying on the default time zone.  Specify both time zones, and the conversion should work.

```
28/09/2016 12:27:00 -> 28/09/2016 16:27:00 +0000
```

And here's some test code.

```
package com.ggl.testing;

import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.TimeZone;

public class TimeZoneConversion {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SimpleDateFormat sdInput = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
        sdInput.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("US/Eastern"));
        SimpleDateFormat sdOutput = new SimpleDateFormat(
                "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss Z");
        sdOutput.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));

        try {
            String dateString = "28/09/2016 12:27:00";
            Date inputDate = sdInput.parse(dateString);
            System.out
                    .println(dateString + " -> " + sdOutput.format(inputDate));
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks @GilbertLeBlanc for the input. You are right, relying on default system time zone was a mistake since WebLogic configuration was  overriding the default timezone and SimpleDateFormat was using the same timezone to convert. So, added explicit timezone in SimpleDateFormat.